# Firebase Call still executing after sending res.status.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following in the my code. I'm trying to prevent a user from reviewing someone twice so therefore it should stop executing code in the IF statement and end firebase calls.

However, it continues executing the rest of the ".then" statements. I tried changing it to end() but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

```
exports.reviewUser = (req, res) => {
  db.collection("users")
    .doc("user")
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ error: "You cannot review someone twice." })
          .send();
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      //Additional functions
    })
    .then(() => {
      //Additional functions
    })
}
```

### **Update:**

I followed the answer and here's my edited code that works for future reference.

```
exports.reviewUser = async(req, res) => {
    let existingReview = await checkReviewExists(userid);

    if (existingReview) {
       return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error: "You cannot review someone twice." })
        .end();
     }

    db.collection("users")
      .doc("user")
      .then(() => {
      //Additional functions
    })
    .then(() => {
      //Additional functions
    })
}

function checkReviewExists(id1) {
  return db
   db.collection("users")
    .doc(id1)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("cannot review twice");
        return true;
      } 
      else 
         return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Firebase doc, we could end HTTP function with `send(), redirect(), or end()`. However, in your case you are resolving the firestore `Promise` with multiple `.then()`. So here, though the first one returns, it goes to the second `then()`

> It's called [Promises chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

The above reference gives detailed info with examples. I prefer to go with one `.then()` or simply async / await would do the work.

Comment: Thank you I just threw an await statement in there BEFORE doing any database editing. I edited my question to show my answer.